# TypeScript add custom Request header in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, http-headers, nestjs

I am trying to add a **custom header** to my request, but it must be modified/implemented in the interface.

The default `Request` interface references `IncomingHttpHeaders`. So I am attempting to extend this interface with my own custom token header.

```
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface IncomingHttpHeaders {
        "XYZ-Token"?: string
    }
}
```

I have updated my `.tsconfig` file to read the `./types` folder. The name of my file is `index.d.ts`

I can successfully compile the code if I do not use my custom header, but when I try to reference the token header in the code I get the following compilation error:

**Error**

```
error TS2538: Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type.

    req.headers['XYZ-Token']
```

If I use any of the values of the original interface everything works fine.

**Example:**

```
    req.headers['user-agent']
```

**Additional information**: I am using NestJS, which uses Fastify/Express under the hood. I can confirm that the Request interface being used is from Express. Fastify is backwards compatible with all Express modules. Mainly using Fastify because it's faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like the wrong module name is in the declaration.

Even though the `IncomingHttpHeaders` interface is being attached to the `Request` object from `express-serve-static-core`, the original source of the `IncomingHttpHeaders` interface is actually part of the `http` package.

The following allowed the custom header to be accessible in the code and ts compiled correctly.

```
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';

declare module 'http' {
    interface IncomingHttpHeaders {
        "XYZ-Token"?: string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it thinks the string you are passing in is an array, but besides that point, if you need to set a custom header (and it is not a dynamic value) you can use the `@Header()` decorator. If it is dynamic then you can use an interceptor to grab the response  pre-flight and set the header there with something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomHeaderInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => context.switchToHttp().getResponse().header('XYZ-Token', customValue),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information on the @Headers. I was able to get my code working with the new header by extending the IncomingHttpHeaders interface. I needed this change globally throughout my API. Looks like when I was declaring the new type, I was still specifying the express-serve-static-sore, where it needed to be http module.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem like this recently, and the solution that worked for me was creating a type that extends from `IncomingHttpHeaders`

```
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from "http2";

interface MyCustomsHearders {
    foo: "bar";
}

type IncomingCustomHeaders = IncomingHttpHeaders & MyCustomsHearders;
const { foo } = req.headers as IncomingCustomHeaders;
```

I know it's not quite the most "formal" way to solve the problem, but it worked fine for me.